# I am making a text based game in unity (5.2.3) I am stuck at this:

Tags: c#, arrays, string, unity-game-engine, queue

This is what the game looks like:

[image: Prototype1]

The player has to click on the word in the lower half in the correct order of the upper paragraph.

For example, The upper paragraph starts with "This", the user has to find and touch "This" on the lower half. He gets 3 tries to get it right. If he clicks on the wrong word, he looses a life.

**In my code**, I have managed to separate the words in the first string by checking for spaces and dots in between them and used a StringBuilder to add individual letters and later transfer that to another string that stores the whole word.

```
//Proper Working Code

public class Queue2Test : MonoBehaviour {

    private string paraString = "This is not the end of the line. This is only the beginning. It cannot get much worse.";
    private StringBuilder buffer;
    private string finalString;
    private int counter;

    void Start () {
        buffer = new StringBuilder ();
        finalString = null;
        counter = 0;
        dothis ();
    }

    void dothis () {

        for (counter = 0; counter < paraString.Length; counter++) {
            buffer = buffer.Append(paraString[counter]);
            if (paraString[counter] == ' ' || paraString[counter] == '.') {
                //buffer.Remove(counter,1);
                finalString = buffer.ToString();
                buffer.Length = 0;
                print (finalString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which works. The output of the above code is all the words printed one by one. Now what I want to do is, change this in such a way that each word prints only when I click on the mouse. And to do that I did this:

```
// This code needs editing: 

public class Queue3Test : MonoBehaviour {

    private string paraString = "This is not the end of the line. This is only the beginning. It cannot get much worse.";
    private StringBuilder buffer;
    private string finalString;
    private int counter;
    private bool flag;
    private int tempvalue;

    void Start () {
        buffer = new StringBuilder ();
        finalString = null;
        counter = 0;
        flag = false;
        tempvalue = 0;
    }

    void Update () {
        if (flag) {
            dothis ();
        }
    }

    void OnMouseDown () {
        flag = true;
        //print (flag);
    }

    void dothis () {
        for (counter = tempvalue; counter < paraString.Length; counter++) {
            buffer = buffer.Append(paraString[counter]);
            if (flag) {
                if (paraString[counter] == ' ' || paraString[counter] == '.') {
                    //buffer.Remove(counter,1);
                    finalString = buffer.ToString();
                    buffer.Length = 0;
                    print (finalString);
                    tempvalue = counter;
                    flag = false;
                    continue;
                }
                //break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code's output is this:

```
This //First Click
is not the end of the line. This is only the beginning. It cannot get much worse. //Second Click
```

This code prints the first line after the first click and on the second click it prints the remaining line all at once!
**I want each word printed separately one after the other *on mouse click*.**

I click on a small collider on the right side of the paragraph to invoke the mouse click function.

I am fairly new to programming using C# and I am making this game for my college project. Any help in this will be useful or just point me towards the right direction. I would definitely mention the answerers name on the game's credits!!!

Thanks. :)

Comment: Try to put `break;` instead of `continue;` in the last loop in your code

Comment: @ClaudiuGeorgiu I did that, but it doesn't work. It puts me out of the loop and there is no way to resume the loop again from outside the loop. :(

Answer (score 1):

First of all, regarding your first problem.
All you have to do is call

```
words = paraString
    .Split(new[] { ' ', '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .ToList();
```

this will return you an array of words, ignoring all the whitespace and empty ones. From here on out you can do something like this:

```
void OnMouseDown() {
    var wordToShow = words.Skip(currentWord).FirstOrDefault();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(wordToShow)) {
        currentWord++;
        Debug.Log(wordToShow);
    } else {
        Debug.Log("Nothing left...");
    }
}
```

Just be sure to store words list as private field of your behaviour script like this:

```
private IList<string> words;
```

You can initialize it by splitting your input string in the Start() or Awake() functions. I would use start.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should avoid this style of naming variables and functions (flag, dothis).
At second, you've chose not appropriate solution to solve the task. It can be resolved much simplier.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Queue3Test : MonoBehaviour {

    private string paraString = "This is not the end of the line. This is only the beginning. It cannot get much worse.";
    private string[] words;
    private int counter = 0;

    private void Start()
    {
        InitializeParaString();
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        ShowNextWord();
    }

    private void InitializeParaString()
    {
        counter = 0;
        words = paraString.Split(new[] { '.', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }

    private void ShowNextWord()
    {
        if (counter < words.Length)
        {
            print(words[counter]);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Good Luck!